# Creating a program header with read only flag causes segfault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, elf

I've been writing ELF binaries using NASM, and I created a segment with the read-only flag turned on. Running the program causes a segfault. I tested the program in replit, and it ran just fine so what's the problem? I created a regular NASM hello world program with the hello world string inside the .rodata section and that ran fine. I checked the binary with readelf to make sure the string was in a read only segment.

The only solution I've come up with is to set the executable flag in the rodata segment so it has read / execute permissions, but that's hacky and I'd like the rodata segment to be read-only.

This is the code for the ELF-64 hello world.

```
; hello.asm
[bits 64]
[org 0x400000]

fileHeader:
    db 0x7F, "ELF"
    db 2 ; ELF-64
    db 1 ; little endian
    db 1 ; ELF version
    db 0 ; System V ABI
    db 0 ; ABI version
    db 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ; unused
    dw 2 ; executable object file
    dw 0x3E ; x86-64
    dd 1 ; ELF version
    dq text ; entry point
    dq 64 ; program header table offset
    dq nullSection - $$ ; section header table offset
    dd 0 ; flags
    dw 64 ; size of file header
    dw 56 ; size of program header
    dw 3 ; program header count
    dw 64 ; size of section header
    dw 4 ; section header count
    dw 3 ; section header string table index
nullSegment:
    times 56 db 0
textSegment:
    dd 1 ; loadable segment
    dd 0x4 ; read / execute permissions
    dq text - $$ ; segment offset
    dq text ; virtual address of segment
    dq 0 ; physical address of segment
    dq textSize ; size of segment in file
    dq textSize ; size of segment in memory
    dq 0x1000 ; alignment
rodataSegment:
    dd 1 ; loadable segment
    dd 0x4 ; read permission (setting this flag to 0x5 causes the program to run just fine)
    dq rodata - $$ ; segment offset
    dq rodata ; virtual address of segment
    dq 0 ; physical address of segment
    dq rodataSize ; size of segment in file
    dq rodataSize ; size of segment in memory
    dq 0x1000 ; alignment
text:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, messageLength
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall
textSize equ $ - text
rodata:
    message db "Hello world!", 0xA, 0
    messageLength equ $ - message
rodataSize equ $ - rodata
stringTable:
    db 0
    db ".text", 0
    db ".rodata", 0
    db ".shstrtab", 0
stringTableSize equ $ - stringTable
nullSection:
    times 64 db 0
textSection:
    dd 1 ; index into string table
    dd 1 ; program data
    dq 0x6 ; occupies memory & executable
    dq text ; virtual address of section
    dq text - $$ ; offset of section in file
    dq textSize ; size of section in file
    dq 0 ; unused
    dq 0x1000 ; alignment
    dq 0 ; unused
rodataSection:
    dd 7 ; index into string table
    dd 1 ; program data
    dq 0x2 ; occupies memory
    dq rodata ; virtual address of section
    dq rodata - $$ ; offset of section in file
    dq rodataSize ; size of section in file
    dq 0 ; unused
    dq 0x1000 ; no alignment
    dq 0 ; unused
stringTableSection:
    dd 15 ; index into string table
    dd 3 ; string table
    dq 0 ; no attributes
    dq stringTable ; virtual address of section
    dq stringTable - $$ ; offset of section in file
    dq stringTableSize ; size of section in file
    dq 0 ; unused
    dq 0 ; no alignment
    dq 0 ; unused
```

replitHello.asm: https://hastebin.com/ujanoguveq.properties // it should be nearly the same line for line

This is the minimal nasm hello world program.

```
; helloNasm.asm
section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, messageLength
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall

section .rodata
    message db "Hello NASM!", 0xA, 0
    messageLength equ $ - message
```

Comment: _"Uhuuh, elf segment at 0000000000400000 requested but the memory is mapped already"_

Comment: @Jester I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: That's what the kernel said :) Anyway looks like you try to map rodata and text to the same page with different permissions. Move the rodata away in virtual address space.

Comment: please create a [mcve] and post all the code here. People won't click on external links, and those links are prone to link rot, which makes the question invalid

Comment: @phuclv I inlined the code here, I still left a to the replit code since it's basically the same, this is as minimal as I can get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
textSegment:
    dd 1 ; loadable segment
    dd 0x4 ; read / execute permissions
```

I assume you meant `0x5` for flags above.

With that fixed, I see the following segments:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  NULL           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000     0
  LOAD           0x0000e8 0x00000000004000e8 0x0000000000000000 0x000025 0x000025 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x00010d 0x000000000040010d 0x0000000000000000 0x00000e 0x00000e R   0x1000
```

This asks the kernel to perform two `mmap`s at the same address (`0x400000`). The second of these `mmap`s maps over the first one, resulting in the following `/proc/$pid/maps`:

```
00400000-00401000 r--p 00000000 fe:02 22548440                           /tmp/t
7ffff7ff9000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffdd000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
```

As you can see, the program text is *not* executable, and as a result the program `SIGSEGV`s on the very first instruction:

```
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /tmp/t 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004000e8 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x4000e8:    mov    $0x1,%eax
```

To fix this, you *must* move one of the segments to a different page (as Jester correctly noted).

Also note that *sections* are completely unnecessary (only segments matter). Setting `A X` flags in the `.text` section in particular has no effect on anything.

Comment: After a bit of testing adding 0x1000 to the virtual address field for the rodata segment fixed it, I don't really understand why it's working so well though.